# How to find the maximum value of an integer that satisfies some inequality

Tags: equation-solving, mathematical-optimization

Consider the following Mathematica expression:

```
Reduce[2^j/(j + 1) <= 10, j, Integers]
```

which outputs:

```
j == 0 || j == 1 || j == 2 || j == 3 || j == 4 || 
j == 5 || j == 6 || (j ∈ Integers && j <= -2)
```

Therefore, the maximum integer $j$ satisfying $\frac{2^j}{j + 1}$ is 6.

I tried to using the function `FindMaximum`, as follows:

```
FindMaximum[{j, 2^j/(j + 1) <= 10 && j ∈ Integers}, j]
```

but it gives the following error:

```
FindMaximum::eqineq: "Constraints in {j∈Integers,2^j/(1+j)<=10} are 
not all equality or inequality constraints. 
With the exception of integer domain constraints for linear programming, 
domain constraints or constraints with Unequal (!=) are not supported."
```

My general question is:

> How to solve inequalities like $\frac{2^j}{j + 1} \le c$ (for some constant $c$) in Mathematica, over Integers?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your approach to solve for general `j` using `Reduce` is correct. However, you can also use `Maximize` or `NMaximize` as:

```
Maximize[{j, 2^j/(j + 1) <= 10}, j, Integers]
(* {6, {j -> 6}} *)
```

Or even more compactly, as JM notes:

```
ArgMax[{j, 2^j/(j + 1) <= 10}, j, Integers]
(* 6 *)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is there a way to put this maximum value into another variable, say $k$?

Comment: @SadeqDousti You can do `k = j /. Last@Maximize[...]` (fill in the rest from above)

Comment: Or alternately, `k = First@Maximize[...]`, since the function being maximized is just `j`.

Comment: More compactly: `ArgMax[{j, 2^j/(j + 1) <= 10}, j, Integers]`.

Comment: @J.M.: That's really compact. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the results from `Reduce`, you could do:

```
Max[j /. Solve@ Reduce[2^j/(j + 1) <= 10, j, Integers]]
```

Comment: except that it doesn't generalize to situations where the actual answer is in the `j ∈ Integers && j ...` case :) For example, find the minimum $j$ such that $2^j/(j+1)\geq 4$. `Reduce[2^j/(j + 1) >= 4, j, Integers]` will give `j ∈ Integers && j >= 5` which will lead to errors with `Solve`. But something in the spirit of what you're doing would be: `Maximize[{j, Reduce[2^j/(j + 1) <= 10, j, Integers]}, j]`

Comment: @R.M Well, your answer does not return `Infinity` for `Maximize[j, 2^j/(j + 1) >= 4, j, Integers]` either :)

Comment: Yes, but that seems more like a bug in `Maximize` when given a constraint. Compare: `Maximize[{x, x > 2}, x, Integers]` with `Maximize[{x}, x, Integers]`. This is a bug worth being aware though... I can think of a few instances where this would've misled me.

Comment: @R.M Let's continue this in a proper duel

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to define a function to return your maximum integer. First, note the output of [`Reduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce) for a couple examples:

```
Reduce[2^j/(j+1) <= 10, j]
Reduce[2^j/(j+1) <= 20, j]
```

> j < -1 || (-Log[2] - ProductLog[-(Log[2]/20)])/Log[2] <= 
>     j <= (-Log[2] - ProductLog[-1, -(Log[2]/20)])/Log[2]
>
> j < -1 || (-Log[2] - ProductLog[-(Log[2]/40)])/Log[2] <= 
>     j <= (-Log[2] - ProductLog[-1, -(Log[2]/40)])/Log[2]

This suggests that the following function returns your desired values:

```
maxj[c_] := Floor[(-Log[2]-ProductLog[-1,-(Log[2]/(2c))])/Log[2]]
```

*(Alternatively, we can use the boundary of the inequality to arrive at the same result)*:

```
Reduce[2^j/(j+1) == c && j > 0 && c > 1, j]
```

> c > 1 && j == (-Log[2] - ProductLog[-1, -(Log[2]/(2 c))])/Log[2]

Check:

```
maxj[10]
```

> 6